# I'm receiving Whatsapp notifications as Twitter notifications

Tags: 7.5, notifications, whatsapp, twitter

Everytime I receive a Whatsapp message, my HTC 7 Trophy shows a Twitter toast notification. That is, a toast notification is shown with the Twitter logo, but the content of the Whatsapp message, and if I tap the toast, Twitter app is launched. Twitter's tile also shows the number of notifications, while Whatsapp's tile doesn't. However, if I launch Whatsapp, I have new messages there.

Sumarizing, I receive Whatsapp notifications as they would be Twitter notifications. It seems push channels are messed up.

Is anyone else seeing this behavior? It's happening to me for the last 2 days.

Comment: Hi ! Did you try to reinstall both applications (Twitter and Facebook) ? Better : try to uninstall both, and only reinstall Facebook, to see if the problem persist.

Comment: Wow, that's weird. When I uninstalled Twitter, I started receiving Whatsapp notifications as LINE notifications. I have uninstalled Whatsapp too now, and reinstalled it. Let's see what happens...

Comment: @MichaëlPolla You meant "Whatsapp" not "Facebook", right?

Comment: Do update your question based on what you observe going forward

Comment: @VitorCanova : Oops ! Of course I meant "Whatsapp"... :-D

anderZubi : Is your problem solved ?

Comment: After reinstallin Whatsapp, I kept receiving notifications as LINE notifications for a while, but now it seems it's working. Anyway, I think that Whatsapp in WP sucks. I receive the notifications late, and duplicated.

Comment: I know, right ? I got the same duplicate notifications problem :-(

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this you need to do the following:

1. **Uninstall** both WhatsApp and Twitter.
2. **Restart** your phone.
3. **Install** WhatsApp and Twitter again.

*If that does not help:*

1. *Try the solution above a few more times.*
2. *If that does not work do a factory reset of your phone.*
3. *If that does not do the job either, send your phone to a repair center.*